# How to update pyqtgraph on select a serial port to plot data

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2, pyqtgraph

I'm writing a script to plot data from a serial port when I select this one in a Combobox. I have two variables to store data: hour and temperature. But the pyqtgraph is not working, to update. What I'm doing wrong. I've tried also to create a timer to clear data and restart but was not been successful.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QComboBox, QVBoxLayout,  QWidget, QVBoxLayout
    from PySide2.QtCore import QSize, QTimer
   

    from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
    import pyqtgraph as pg

     import sys  

     import serial.tools.list_ports
     from datetime import datetime

      comlist = serial.tools.list_ports.comports() 
      connected = [] 
      for element in comlist: 
      connected.append(element.device) 


      now = datetime.now()
      date_now = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
     
       hour = []
        temperature = []

    class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Raspberry Pico Monitor")  
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(600, 500)) 
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout() 

       
        self.cmbox = QComboBox()
       
        self.cmbox.addItems(connected)

        
        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        
       
       
       
        layout.addWidget(self.cmbox)
        layout.addWidget(self.graphWidget)
       
       
        styles = {"color": "#E1AF67", "font-size": "12px"}
        self.graphWidget.setLabel("left", "Temperature (°C)", **styles)
        self.graphWidget.setLabel("bottom", "Hour (H)", **styles)
        self.graphWidget.setBackground("#1F2832")

        self.graphWidget.addLegend()
        self.graphWidget.setLabel('left', 'Temperature', units ='y')
 
       
        self.graphWidget.setLabel('bottom', 'hour', units ='s')
        self.graphWidget.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255,175,113))

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout) 
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        
        self.cmbox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.index_changed)
        
        
        self.graphWidget.plot(hour, temperature, name = "Raspberry Pico", pen = pen, color = 'black', symbol='t1', symbolSize=12, symbolBrush=('b'))
        
    def index_changed(self):
       port = self.cmbox.currentText() 
       if port in connected:
            print(
                port + " is available to read data ...")  
            baud_rate = 115200  
           
            ser = serial.Serial("{}".format(port), baud_rate)

            if (ser.isOpen()):  
                print("This port is alredy open")
                while True:
                    self.data = ser.readline()
                    self.update_plot_data() 
            else:
                print("Check the available ports and try again")
                print(connected)

    def update_plot_data(self):
      
       hour = date_now
       temperature = float(self.data)
       print(temperature, hour)

      
   app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
   window = MainWindow()  
   window.show()  
   app.exec_()
```

[terminal img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLS7d.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `while True: ser.readline()` in gui thread (main thread), you need to either move serial operations to separate `QThread` (create worker and connect to it using signal-slot mechanism) or use `QtSerialPort` instead of `serial` module.